# Publish to redis is blocking my process

Tags: ruby, redis

this is my ruby code:

```
require 'redis'
redis = Redis.new

Thread.new do
  redis.subscribe('foo_bar') do |on|
    on.message do |key, id|
      puts id
    end
  end
end

redis.publish('foo_bar', 1337)
```

Can anyone tell me, why the "publish" instruction in last line is blocking my process?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that `redis.subscribe` blocks redis access in the entire process. So when you try to publish it locks.

Solution: trying using polling instead of `subscribe`

Solution 2: use several REDIS connections, i.e. create REDIS connection pool

Answer (score 0):

To start with, the publish isnt blocking the process.

```
require 'redis'
redis = Redis.new

Thread.new do
  redis.subscribe('foo_bar') do |on|
    on.message do |key, id|
      puts id
    end
  end
end

redis.publish('foo_bar', 1337)
```

Should output:

```
1337
```

And also,

```
require 'redis'
redis = Redis.new

Thread.new do
  redis.subscribe('foo_bar') do |on|
    on.message do |key, id|
      puts id
    end
  end
end

redis.publish('foo_bar', 1337)
redis.publish('foo_bar', 1338)
```

Would output:

```
1337
1338
```

In the pub/sub system, the publisher pushes the message, and the subscriber is an always blocking synchronous process. Publisher is always asynchronous.

Comment: Your explanation is exactly what I expected when working with redis pub/sub. But the process will get a deadlock after the command publish on my machine. If I use a separate connection to redis, the deadlock does not appear while the command uses this connection.

Comment: Using two separate `redis = Redis.new` connections solved it for me, thanks for the tip.